# (Scikit-learn) differences between LinearSVC, 'linear' kernel SVC and poly kernel SVC with degree 1

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I would like to know the differences between:

- `linearSVC()`
- `SVC(kernel='lineaer)`
- `SVC(kernel='poly', degree=1)`

Will these all determine the same boundary decisions?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [the user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-classification) that the first two will not produce the same results.  In the multiclass setting, LinearSVC uses one-vs-rest while SVC uses one-vs-one.  Aside from that, the solver used is also different, and because of that some of the options differ.  See [LinearSVC docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC), [SVC docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC).

I suspect the third will be the same as the second.  I don't see anything in the source to indicate it quickly, but it shouldn't take long to test.

Answer (score 1):

None of them are the same.
linearSVC() uses one-vs-rest and SVC(kernel='linear) uses one-vs-one for classification.

To have the same results with the SVC poly kernel as with the SVC linear we have to set the gamma parameter to 1 otherwise the default is to use 1 / (n_features * X.var) weakening the value from the now linear kernel.